# Utility shop database schema

Tags: sql, database

i am trying to make database schema for a shop they have stock of products and walk in customers (so no need to record customers).

1 - need to record for stock . 
2 - products
3 - selling products

i made tables for category , products , stock 
 now i am thinking for table for bill , i need to indicate all products with their price and quantity sold on bill slip.

so how to implement that ,

**should i record each product with price and quantity for separate row with same bill no ,  or is there any better way.**

simply finding solution to generate list of item sold with quantity and price for each item and sum up of total bill .

thanks in advance

Comment: at the end i also need to generate reporting for profit and loss

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would use two tables.

`Invoices` : InvoiceID, InvoiceDate, CustomerID, EmployeeID

and

`LineItems` : LineItemID, `InvoiceID`, ProductID, Name, Qty, UnitPrice

See how LineItems contains a foreign key to Invoices...

Comment: These schemas are demonstrative and not meant to model any particular real-world system.